# SQL: Report instances where only one of two possible value exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm stuck trying to figure this out...
I have two data sets.
security_account.name and spot.format.
I need to find out which accounts ONLY contain spots with values of 'SD'.

This query:

```
select distinct
sa.name as "Sender Account"
from
security_account sa,
spot s
where
sa.id = s.provider_account_id
and s.format = 'SD';
```

Gives me a list of every account that has an SD spot, if I say != 'HD', I get the same results. Most accounts have HD and SD, I only want to see the accounts that ONLY CONTAIN SD in the spot table.

Any ideas?

Thank You, Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `except`.

```
select sa.name as "Sender Account"
from security_account sa
join spot s on sa.id = s.provider_account_id
where s.format = 'SD'
except
select sa.name as "Sender Account"
from security_account sa
join spot s on sa.id = s.provider_account_id
where s.format <> 'SD'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select sa.name as "Sender Account"
from security_account sa
where exists (select *
               from spot s
              where s.provider_account_id = sa.id
                and s.format = 'SD')
  and not exists (select *
                   from spot s
                  where s.provider_account_id = sa.id
                    and s.format = 'HD')
```